# Mongodb update and delete fields that no longer exist

Tags: mongodb

There is a document, i.e.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63ee577ca5340cd594916852"
  },
  "id": 12345,
  "price": 123,
  "oldprice": 456
}
```

I am performing an update with

```
db.testupd.updateOne({'id': 12345}, [{'$set': {"id": 12345, "price": 222}}], upsert=true)
```

It works but "oldprice" field is still there after update and what I need is to delete the fields that no longer exist, because unfortunately the data source is not consistent.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you know all the fields that you don't want anymore, you can simply `$unset` them

Comment: @ray unfortunately I do not know all of the fields it can be one or another from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of fields that you do not want to keep is unknown, using `replace` in `$merge` is one of the options. You can `$project` to keep only the fields you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": 12345
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "id": 12345,
      "price": 222
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      price: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CLDwzDVMYjt)